# Switch Condition in Laravel service provider

Tags: laravel-5, switch-statement, service-provider

I was trying to get a french month using service provider.

my code is,

```
Blade::directive('frenchmonth', function($arguments){

       switch($arguments)
 {

     case "January":
     $frmonth="Janvier";
     break;

     case "February":
     $frmonth="Février";
     break;

     case "March":
     $frmonth="Mars";
     break;
}

 return "<?php echo \"{$frmonth}\"; ?>";

        });
```

But it returns Undefined variable: frmonth.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You just must declare the variable outside the switch case statment like this `$frmonth = ""; switch($arguments){....}`